# How do I combine the Command Pattern with a JavaFX GUI?

Tags: java, oop, javafx, actionevent

My current Controller class

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
public javafx.scene.image.ImageView imageView;


@FXML
private MenuItem openItem;

@FXML
public void openAction(ActionEvent event) {
    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    File file = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    try {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
        Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
        imageView.setImage(image);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("lol");
    }


}
```

How would I be able to place the openAction function logic in its own class? I need to add about 10 - 20 functions with their own actionevent listeners for my UI and I dont want to have all of these functions existing in this one controller class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear in what context you want to use the pattern, so I'm showing an example conversion that accepts the address of the window (that is, to submit it as the owner of the dialogs that are displayed).

It starts with an interface that describes the command (in this case I chose to return `Optional`)

```
public interface Command<R> {
    public Optional<R> execute();
}
```

The implementation of the `Command` interface in an abstract class follows.

```
public abstract class AbstractCommand<R> implements Command<R> {

    private Window window;

    public AbstractCommand(Window window) {
        this.window = window;
    }

    public Window getWindow() {
        return window;
    }
}
```

From here on, we can do as much as we want implementations either by realizing `Command` or by extending `AbstractCommand`.

This is an example implementation of the load image command

```
public class LoadImageCommand extends AbstractCommand<Image> {

    public LoadImageCommand() {
        this(null);
    }

    public LoadImageCommand(Window window) {
        super(window);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Image> execute() {
        Image image = null;

        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
        File file = fc.showOpenDialog(getWindow());
        try {
            if(file != null) {
                BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
                image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("lol");
        }

        return Optional.ofNullable(image);
    }
}
```

Using the command:

```
@FXML
private void openAction(ActionEvent event) {
    new LoadImageCommand().execute().ifPresent(imageView::setImage);
}
```

If you want to use openAction in different controllers and do not want to create separate instances of `Command`, inherit `Controller`.